# How can we derive an equation for double slit interference without the approximations made?

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference, double-slit-experiment

I'm referring to:
$$s = D\lambda/d$$
Where $s$ is the distance to the first constructive interference (CI) from the central line, $D$ is the distance from the point sources to the screen, $d$ is the distance between the two point sources, and lambda is the wavelength.

I'm trying to derive an equation using path difference that would allow me to obtain more accurate results for smaller Ds as the angles between each point source and the point of CI on the screen become larger and larger, rendering the approximation that all the angles are the same and that $\theta = sin(\theta)$ redundant. I have managed to derive an equation for the path difference and thus CI as when the path difference us equated to $m\lambda$, where $m$ is an integer, you get the CI. However, this is providing extremely anomalous results and is not consistent with experimental values (i'm performing the experiment with sound: 2 identical speakers playing a monotone through a sine synth).

I'm afraid I've misunderstood something and am hence struggling to work with this. I'm hoping someone could point out gaps in my logic.

Comment: You can find the full Fresnell equations anywhere, including wikipedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For near-field effects, it may be better to think about the full field rather than just path differences.  Based on you wording of "point sources" and the fact that you are using speakers, I will assume that you are looking for the interference pattern of two monopole sources rather than the pattern of the double slit experiment, which would be line sources.

The pressure from a point source may be written as
$$p = \frac{Ae^{ikr}}{r},$$
where $p$ is the acoustic pressure, $A$ is an amplitude factor, $k$ is the wavenumber ($2\pi$ over the wavelength $\lambda$), $r$ is the distance from the source to the measurement location.  Implied is a time dependence of $e^{-i\omega t}$, and the real part is assumed.  Letting two identical point sources exist at $y,z=0$ and $x=\pm d$, we then obtain a full pressure field given by
$$p = A\left[ \frac{e^{ik\sqrt{(x-d/2)^2+y^2+z^2}}}{\sqrt{(x-d/2)^2+y^2+z^2}} + \frac{e^{ik\sqrt{(x+d/2)^2+y^2+z^2}}}{\sqrt{(x+d/2)^2+y^2+z^2}} \right].$$
For simplicity and without loss of generality we will assume that $z=0$ at the measurement location.  The interference pattern discussed in the original post would then be the location of local maxima of $p$ for a set value of $y$.

Consider the case where $y>d,x$ (measurement site is farther from the sources than the sources are separate and we are looking at positions that are closer than the measurement site is from the sources).  In this case the distance from the sources to the measurement location may be expanded as
$$\sqrt{(x\pm d/2)^2+y^2} = \alpha \pm \beta,$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
\begin{align}
 \alpha &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x+d/2)^2+y^2} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x-d/2)^2+y^2}, \\
 \beta &= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x+d/2)^2+y^2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(x-d/2)^2+y^2}.
\end{align}
Approximate expressions for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may be found by expanding the square roots in a Taylor series and isolating terms that differ by the presence of the $\pm$ symbol.  To $O(d^6/y^6)$ we may write
\begin{align}
 \alpha &= y + \frac{x^2+d^2/4}{y} + \frac{x^6+(3/2)x^2d^2+d^6/64}{y^3}, \\
 \beta &= \frac{xd}{2y} - \frac{2xd}{y^3}(x^2+d^2/4).
\end{align}
Substituting this expression the acoustic pressure expression we may then write
$$p = Ae^{ik\alpha}\left[ \frac{e^{- ik\beta}}{\alpha - \beta} + \frac{e^{ik\beta}}{\alpha + \beta} \right] = Ae^{ik\alpha}\left[ \frac{2\alpha\cos(k\beta)-2i\beta\sin(k\beta)}{\alpha^2-\beta^2} \right].$$
Loud spots will be at the local maxima of the pressure magnitude squared, which is given by
$$|p|^2 = 4|A|^2\frac{\alpha^2\cos^2(k\beta)+\beta^2\sin^2(k\beta)}{(\alpha^2-\beta^2)^2}.$$

It is important to validate the above expression.  In the limit that $y\rightarrow\infty$, we find that $\alpha\rightarrow y$ and $\beta\rightarrow xd/2y$, and so we may write
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}|p|^2 \rightarrow \frac{-kd\sin(kdx/y)}{2y^3}.$$
Thus, there are extrema near $\sin(kdx/y)=0$, or $x = n\pi y/kd = ny\lambda/2d$, where $n$ is any integer.  We know that $n=0$ corresponds to a maximum, and so the maxima occur at the standard prediction of $x=n\lambda/d$.  Thus, the above expression for the acoustic pressure magnitude squared passes this validation test.